# starting data node on the worker node throws this error

Tags: hadoop, namenode

I am using hadoop-2.5.1 and hbase-1.0.1

when i start the datanode on a worker node by

```
hadoop-daemon.sh start datanode
```

it throws `SLF4J:class path contains multiple  SLF4J bindings`

and data node is not getting started

Comment: Both Hadoop and Hbase have slf4j jars in their `lib`, which is part of the classpath. Can you remove the slf4j jar from $HBASE_HOME/lib and try?

Answer (score 0):

I encounter the same error while installing hive .
the simple solution for it is to remove the slf4j jar file from folder in hive due to which this multiple jar error is appearing.

Now there are multiple slf4j jar file so in your error log check which slf4j jar is causing error most probably it will be slf4j-log4j12 or something like that. it actually depend on your hive and Hadoop version.

This error occur because the same jar is present in Hadoop lib folder which contains all the jar related to hadoop and also  in hive lib folder. Now when we install hive after hadoop the jar which is common is again added as it is also present in hadoop lib folder thus  it is required to be removed from hive lib folder as hive will automatically detect this jar from Hadoop lib folder due to its dependency on Hadoop. Thus it is safe to remove it from hive lib folder.

Hope this solve your query